# textbox scrolling not fit in windows phone

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, textbox, scrollview

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
     <ScrollViewer  Height="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,0,0,0" Name="scrollViewer1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
         <StackPanel Height="Auto" x:Name="TitlePanelOne" Background="AliceBlue" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
              <toolkit:PhoneTextBox Background="Aquamarine" Hint="tap to enter the title" BorderThickness="2"></toolkit:PhoneTextBox>
              <toolkit:PhoneTextBox Foreground="Black" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" Hint="Tap To entr the Note" BorderThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="textBox1" Width="460"></toolkit:PhoneTextBox>
         </StackPanel>
     </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

The code works fine but the problem is if I type the word in textbox its getting the scrool view.

If I type more lines on textbox the typing line is not showing to the user how to avoid this, any guess?

Answer (score 0):

Just Copy this block instead of your block.

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
      <StackPanel Height="420" x:Name="TitlePanelOne" Background="AliceBlue" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28" Width="400">
         <toolkit:PhoneTextBox Background="Aquamarine" Hint="tap to enter the title" BorderThickness="2"></toolkit:PhoneTextBox>
         <ScrollViewer  Height="320" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Name="scrollViewer1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
              <toolkit:PhoneTextBox Foreground="Black" AcceptsReturn="True" Margin="10,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Hint="Tap To entr the Note" BorderThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="250" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="textBox1" Width="380"></toolkit:PhoneTextBox>
         </ScrollViewer>
     </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Please put the height of text box to show the user's text on typing line easily.

It works as per your Query. Thank You.

I Hope You Get the Solution.